# How can I make a simple form that saves text in the form field?

Tags: html, forms

I would like to make a field on my page that I can click edit, edit it, click save, and have it stay as it is, for all viewers (even new ones, so cookies is out).

This is a page for staff so I'm not worried about people tampering with it.

Comment: Take a look at Powr.io widgets https://www.powr.io/plugins

Comment: Does the text come from a database?  If so, you should be able to accomplish this with a little javascript and a receiving route for an AJAX call.  You'd need to provide more details to come up with a good solution to the problem.

Comment: Yes, it can come from a database or however (I've used some chat/comments php scripts that don't use a DB). Anything that works. 
Essentially, I just want a box that I can edit on the page, to post updated messages for staff.